# jQuery $.post string escape problem

Tags: php, jquery

I am posting data to a php file via jQuery's $.post method, but for some reason the string comes out escaped on the other side, like so,

Sent:
`company_name="company"`

Received: 
`company_name=\"company\"`

Any idea what could be the cause?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you have [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.php) enabled on your server - and, as you see, you should realy disable that to avoid confusing stuff like that (see: [why not to use magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.whynot.php)). (also, this "feature" will be deleted in the future, so you shouldnt rely on that)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have ugly [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on. You should disable them just in case. See how to disable them here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: Thanx for your help! That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) on.  [Turn them off](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php), or, if you can't, use [`stripslashes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove them.